# How to write Inline/Lambda for appending or not appending to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I feel this a noob question but I haven't used lambda functions that much and I couldn't find what I needed online.
I wanted to write a lambda function which takes a series as an input, and returns a list without any 'None's in it
Basically I want a lambda function for the followinf function:

```
def get_path(x):
  toRet = []
  for item in x.tolist():
    if item is not None:
      toret.append(item)
  return toRet
```

Is it possible to get an inline lambda function which does what get_path() does. 
Yes I do know that I can do the following:

```
lambda x: get_path(x)
```

It solves the problem but I would really love to know how to make an inline function for this.

Comment: `lambda x: list(filter(None, x.tolist()))`

Comment: `lambda x: get_path(x)` is pointless, it is equivalent to `get_path`

Comment: The entire thing can be replaced with `[elem if elem is not None for elem in some_series]`. Why do you need to use a lambda?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need lambda functions here.

```
toRet = [item for item in x.tolist() if item is not None]
```

You can also use `filter` for example, which looks neater

```
toRet = list(filter(None, x.tolist()))
```

Comment: Probably he want to use lamda as argument to one of functions.

Comment: As far I understand the question title, he need an **inline** or **lambda** way for doing this.

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use the lambda function as an argument for another function. But thanks, the RHS of the equal to does help

Answer (score 0):

```
get_path = lambda x: [ elem for elem in x.tolist() if not elem]
```

Comment: Can you add some context on how you think this code fixes the issue for OP

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you can use [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) but be careful of what function you provide for the filter-check.

> If *function* is `None` , the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of *iterable* that are false are removed.

`list(filter(None, something))` won't work correctly because it will filter out False-ish values too, not just `None`. Example:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 0, None, '', tuple(), 'last']
>>> list(filter(None, mylist))  # not the expected behaviour
[1, 2, 3, 'last']
```

OP had an explicit `if item is not None` check, rather than just `if item` - so the two are not equivalent. Only `None` needs to be filtered out. To get the correct filtering behaviour, provide an actual check for the function provided to filter:

```
>>> list(filter(lambda i: i is not None, mylist))
[1, 2, 3, 0, '', (), 'last']
```

Replace `mylist` with `x.tolist()`. And when you put that into a lambda, it gets messy:

```
get_path = lambda x: list(filter(lambda i: i is not None, x.tolist()))
```

Instead of all that, the list comprehension option is better:

```
get_path = lambda x: [i for i in x.tolist() if i is not None]
```

with an explicit `is not None` check.